# What does "out of scope" mean in Xcode debugger (for iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm loading a detailed view of an article when clicking on a row in a UITableView. When clicked, it loads the object with the data and I pass that object to the next controller being pushed on the stack. However, when I do this:

```
- (void)showArticle
{
    [aTitle setText:[[self article] title]];
    [aTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[self view] addSubview:aTitle];

    [aCategory setText:[[self article] category]];
    [aCategory setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[self view] addSubview:aCategory];

    [aAuthors setText:[[self article] authors]];
    [aAuthors setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[self view] addSubview:aAuthors];
}
```

The `title` shows up fine, but the `category` and `authors` aren't showing up. When I debug, I'm getting "out of scope" when I look at the values of the category/authors. The `article` object is being @synthesized and I've checked it and it has the right data.

Any ideas? Does that mean that a method is private or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"out of scope" is a general error: sometimes it means that the variable is not initialized or that the variable was released.

It will if the variable was created in a separate thread without being retained.

How do you initialize the article object and where?

Try to retain the article object before calling showArticle method and/or before this line `[aCategory setText:[[self article] category]];`.

Comment: Can you provide any reference for "out of scope" meaning that `release` has been sent to a variable? I don't believe it has anything to do with that.

Comment: I'm initializing the article in the `- (void)init` of the controller, like so: `article = [[Article alloc] init];` - I'm then setting it like this: `article = [parser detailedArticle];` (I've also tried `[self setArticle:[parser detailedArticle]];`) ...I'm somewhat unclear on when you use `object =` vs `[self setObject:obj]` - does `setObject` just get added for convenience when you `@synthesize` something? Or are there core differences in assignment?

Comment: @Chuck When you initialize, for example, a NSArray like this: NSArray *arry = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"String"]; This var is autorelease, so, rarely, "out of scope" could be that the var is autoreleased, without any intervention of the programmer.

-----------------------------------------------------------------


@rpheath: You can find something usefull here: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1193-calling-self-object-rather-than-calling-the-object-directly-in-objective-c/

In addition, try to retain the var (NSMutableDictionary?) in your custum class where you store the article details.

Comment: Alright, I think I figured it out. I was two-purposing the `article` variable from the previous step. Before getting to the detail view, I have a table view filled from articles objects (at this point the objects only have id, title, lastmodified - only the fields I needed for the cells). In order to pass the data to the detail controller, I'm calling `setArticle:a` before pushing it on the nav stack. Then I was trying to reassign that article to the full object, and apparently you can't do that. I changed it to only pass the articleID and do a full refresh, it's now working. Thanks!

Comment: Again, what do retaining and releasing have to do with variable scope?

Answer (score 7):

It means the debugger couldn't see it when it tried to query its value.  Sometimes that means the variable really is out of scope in the sense that it belongs to a C block you are not in.  But there is a glitch where sometimes Objective-C objects, particularly NSStrings appear out of scope when they are really perfectly OK.  It's almost never (in my experience) a programming error.

Try right clicking the variable and selecting "print description to console" if you need to see what the real value is.

Answer (score 1):

After a longtime to workaround this issue, you should use an object when assign to userData event NSString like this:

```
@interface callBackData
 @NSString *text;
 @NSInteger point;
@end
```

use it:

```
callBackData *data = [[callBackData alloc] init];
data.text=[NSString stringWithString:@"something"];
something.userData = data;
```

And you'll be always OK.

**Pls remember do not assign directly NSString for userData, because of sometime it will be out of scope without reason**